# Couchdb crashes due to many changes request from pouch

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

When i"m trying  to sync from pouch and couch. couch crashes due to many request from pouch to couch every change.

somebody can help me?

The code:

```
    function _createTestDB() {
        $log.debug("_createLocalStorage()");

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promise = deferred.promise;
        if (dbInstance) {
            _initIndexes(["type"]).then(function success(response) {
                dbInstance.sync(remoteDB, {live: true,retry: true  , batch_size : 1});

                deferred.resolve();
            }, function failure(error) {
                deferred.reject();
            });
        } else {
            if (ENV.localDbName) {
                dbInstance = new PouchDB(ENV.localDbName);
                _initIndexes(["type"]).then(function success(response) {
                    dbInstance.sync(remoteDB, {live: true,retry: true , batch_size : 1});
                    deferred.resolve();
                }, function failure(error) {
                    deferred.reject();
                });
            } else {
                deferred.reject();
            }
        }
        return promise;
    }
```

thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest checking line 37 of your code for an error...just kidding. Obviously, no one can tell you which line number has an error without seeing the code. :)

Comment: tnx , i forgot that.